# Binding a converter to a MultiBinding in Silverlight

Tags: binding, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

The `Converter` property in the code from the blog post, [Silverlight MultiBinding solution for Silverlight 4](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/), is not a dependency property, so I can't bind it with a converter (that for technical reasons must be instantiated as part of Unity injection earlier in the application rather than as a simple static resource as part of a user control).

How can I modify the `MultiBinding` code to accept a bound converter? I tried to make it a dependency property:

```
public IMultiValueConverter Converter { get { return (IMultiValueConverter)GetValue(ConverterProperty); } set { SetValue(ConverterProperty, value); } }
public static DependencyProperty ConverterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Converter", typeof(IMultiValueConverter), typeof(IMultiValueConverter), null);
```

but I got

> DependencyProperty System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter. Converter cannot be set on an object of type ...Binding.MultiBinding.

If this is not a viable option, how can I bind the `ConverterParameter` property or get something to simulate bindings of a converter to a `MultiBinding`?

Comment: why not bind your data to the MultiBinding too? then you have the data in the multi value converter and your converter also fires if your data changes.

Comment: @punker76, I'm not sure I follow you. I have, for example, 3 properties of a view model multi-bound, but they have to run through a converter to format properly in the view. The converter itself can't (so far as I know) be a static resource because *it* has dependencies injected into its constructor.

Comment: Mh, I have unfortunately not yet understood why you want to bind a converter?

Comment: @punker76, because it is sufficiently complex to create that it's not convenient to make a static resource. The converter uses services to lookup information so that the end-result displayed "looks right" when formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the "simulated bindings" route, though that's not my preference if someone has another answer. What I did instead was not build up the converter via dependency injection, but instead had it use service location to get it's needed dependencies. Generally I prefer dependency injection to service location. The "service location" was a matter of storing the Unity container in the application's global resources; from there it's not difficult to get what I need.

Comment: I don't have this luxury yet, but here's an SL5 solution for anyone who's interested: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightMultiBinding.aspx?display=Mobile